# Powershell script works when executed directly in Powershell, but not when executed from Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a PS script with an embedded condition. If true, it displays a prompt.  If the user enters "R", the PC is supposed to reboot. Everything works well when the script is executed manually, but when executed via Task Scheduler, the task runs, but no prompt is displayed.

In Task Scheduler, History shows the task as having been completed with Operational Code (2).

```
Task Action = -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "{script path}\TimeToReboot.ps1"
```

This is the same action I'm using for other scheduled tasks, which work without issue. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Script shown below.

```
# Definitions
    $RebootTriggerDays = 5
    $CompName = $env:computername

    $RebootTime = (gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
    $TimeSinceReboot = (get-date) - $RebootTime
    $DaysSinceReboot = $TimeSinceReboot.TotalDays # $TimeSinceReboot| Select-Object -ExpandProperty TotalDays
     
if ($DaysSinceReboot -gt $RebootTriggerDays) {
    Write-host $CompName 'last Restarted:' $RebootTime `n 'Days since ReBooting:' ([math]::Round($DaysSinceReboot, 2))

    $Action = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter 'R' to ReBoot now (anything else to skip)"
    if ($Action.ToUpper -eq 'R') { Restart-Computer -ComputerName $CompName -Confirm }
}
```

Comment: Is the task running as the same user that will receive the pop-up?

Comment: Have you tried adding the -Force parameter switch to the Restart-Computer line?

Comment: Thank you both. When the task runs (which it does every day), I do see a Powershell window briefly pop up on my screen, then disappear, which is normal behavior when executing scripts from the Scheduler.
In response to RetiredGeek, the Restart command executes only in response to the user prompt, which never occurs, so that part of the script doesn't execute.